# Is there any way to show a user's current password in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, passwords, user-accounts

I wonder, is there anyway to show a user's current password in Windows 7? (if you are administrator)

I am not at all interested in changing the password, I want only to **view** the password. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

[Dump cleartext passwords of logged in user(s)](https://tinyapps.org/blog/windows/201304110700_dump_passwords.html) explains how to use [mimikatz](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz) to do just that:

```
mimikatz # privilege::debug
Demande d'ACTIVATION du privilège : SeDebugPrivilege : OK

mimikatz # sekurlsa::logonPasswords full
...
Utilisateur principal       : user
Domaine d'authentification  : domain
        kerberos :
         * Utilisateur  : user
         * Domaine      : domain
         * Mot de passe : pass
```

Comment: The only piece of software ever to have non-English command. srsly why?!

Answer (score 3):

No.

By default the password is encrypted and that is stored. The plain text password is **not** stored and thus cannot be viewed. This default can be changed but you have to do that before the user sets the password.

Comment: Where and how can I change that setting?

Comment: You cannot change the way Windows saves passwords without changing the Kernelcode which I dont recommend. Windows only saves a asymetric hash value that cannot be changed back to a password. There are still some hacks how to get in an windows account without the password, incase you lost the password